# GVim - How to handle multiple files

Tags: vim

Sorry to ask such a novice question but I am looking for a way to handle multiple files. I dont want to type huge file paths to open every file using :tabnew and :e commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, **vim** [supports buffers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ) for that. Use `:badd` to add buffer, `:bdelete` to remove it and `:ls` (or `:buffers`) to list all opened buffers. I believe, GVim supports these features too.

For example, if you wanna edit all `.rb` files in your `app/controllers/pages` dir (in the case of Rails project), you type `vim app/controllers/pages/*.rb` in your terminal and then edit the first file (buffer) in the vim window. When you've done with all changes, save changes as usual with `:w` (**note:** do not use `q!` option - this will close all your buffers you've opened) and then use `:bn<tab>` (or fully, `:bnext`) or `:bprevious` to switch to the next file (buffer). When you run `:bnext` on the last buffer, you'll be dropped to the first one.

Comment: Thanks, but are there any file browser plugins ? I installed NERDTree but :NERDTree command fails in vim

Answer (score 5):

[Fuzzy Finder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) is a handy plugin to quickly find and open files.

Basically you have to only type a few letters like `test` and you'll get a pop-up menu to open in your current path :

```
footest.c
bartest.h
footest.h
...
```

It is a bit slow when used on NFS but it is useful if you don't want to type long path and file names.

Alternatively if you don't want to use any plugin, by default gvim/vim includes a file browser called `netrw`.
To start it, just type `:e .` you'll get the content of your current directory, you can then navigate through the directory structure quite easily. (There is even commands to delete, rename, etc like a standard file explorer)

`:help netrw`for more information.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tips that you might be interested in:

- You can configure Vim so that the
  current directory "follows" the
  directory of the file you are
  currently editing. That way you can
  edit another file from the same
  directory without having to type the
  full path. This can be achieved by
  putting either `set autochdir` or
  `autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h` in
  your `.vimrc`
- You can use wildcards with tab
  completion. e.g. to edit
  a_file_with_a_long_name.txt you could
  do `:e a*long` and then press
  <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by
  <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a directory in Vim, search for the file o directory you are looking for with '/' and type [enter] to open it.